# ordem do IN() no mysql

Tags: mysql

Bom estou fazendo o seguinte select:

```
select * from pedidos where id IN (1,3,4,2)
```

Tem alguma forma do mysql me retornar o resultado na mesma ordem em que esta no IN?

Com o select que estou fazendo o mysql esta colocando em ordem crescente e não quero que isso aconteça.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar o operador [FIELD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM pedidos 
 WHERE id IN (1,3,4,2)
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 1, 3, 4, 2)
```

O operador funciona da seguinte forma:

```
FIELD() devolve a posição de um determinado valor (caso este exista) na lista delimitada por virgula.

Se id = 1, FIELD(id,3,2,1,4) devolve 3 (posição do 1 na lista)  
Se id = 2, FIELD(id,3,2,1,4) devolve 2 (posição do 2 na lista) 
Se id = 4, FIELD(id,3,2,1,4) devolve 4 (posição do 4 na lista) 
Se id = 5 ou outro valor que não existe na lista, FIELD(id,3,2,1,4) devolve 0
```

Sabendo isto, pode usar o FIELD para controlar a ordenação. Se quiser que os registos com id na lista (1, 3, 4, 2) sejam listados no topo, basta fazer:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM pedidos 
 WHERE id IN (1,3,4,2)
ORDER BY IF(FIELD(id, 1, 3, 4, 2) = 0, 1, 0), FIELD(id, 1, 3, 4, 2);
```

Comment: isso mesmo, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Apenas como curiosidade, uma alternativa ao [FIELD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
SELECT * 
FROM pedidos 
WHERE id IN (1,3,4,2)
ORDER BY id = 2, id = 4, id = 3, id = 1;
```